# Click and remove/add multiple Classes with multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons:

[image]

When users click on button I need 3 actions:

- The button that users clicked get class `active` and others are removed.
- Remove a list of class in body.
- Add the name of button as class to body.

The code bellow works fine. But I had 20 buttons. And would be a big code.
So my question is: There is a way to simplify what I need to do?

*I saw others questions on stackoverflow, but I did not find what I looking for.*

```js
$("body  .buttons div:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('A B C D');
  $('body').addClass('A');
  $('body .buttons div').removeClass('active');
  $('body .buttons div:nth-child(A)').addClass('active');
});

$("body .buttons div:nth-child(2)").click(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('A B C D');
  $('body').addClass('B');
  $('body .buttons div').removeClass('active');
  $('body .buttons div:nth-child(B)').addClass('active');
});

$("body .buttons div:nth-child(3)").click(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('A B C D');
  $('body').addClass('C');
  $('body .buttons div').removeClass('active');
  $('body .buttons div:nth-child(C)').addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="1">1</div>
  <div class="2">2</div>
  <div class="3">3</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sthvo31v/

Comment: Please show us all relevant code.

Comment: I did. It's just an example.

Comment: The HTML code of a set of buttons would be useful as well

Comment: OK. I'll update the question.

Comment: calling a class `1` seems somewhat shortsighted

Comment: I edited the question and add a jsfiddle example.

Comment: @Liam its not only shortsighted but it's also invalid css, since CSS classes are required to start with a letter.

Comment: I already put as letters. Thanks.

Comment: I've looked through these answers and couldn't find the simplest solution i could think of . See my answer below and please let me know it that is what you were looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was change your code:

html:

```
<body>
<div class="buttons"> 
<div class="1" data-class="A">1</div>
<div class="2" data-class="B">2</div>
<div class="3" data-class="C">3</div>
</div>
</body>
```

js:

```
$(".buttons div").click(function(){
    var activeClass = $(".buttons div.active").data("class");

  $(".buttons div").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $("body").removeClass(activeClass);
  $("body").addClass($(this).data("class"));
});
```

Comment: Perfect! It change just the selected class. Worked like a charm. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with just ordinary js, like this:

```js
function buttonClicked() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.myButton').forEach(button => {
    button.classList.remove('active');
  });
  
  this.classList.add('active');
}

document.querySelectorAll('.myButton').forEach(button => {
  button.onclick = buttonClicked;
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton">1</button>
<button class="myButton">2</button>
<button class="myButton">3</button>
<button class="myButton">4</button>
<button class="myButton">5</button>
<button class="myButton">6</button>
<button class="myButton">7</button>
<button class="myButton">8</button>
<button class="myButton">9</button>
<button class="myButton">10</button>
<button class="myButton">11</button>
<button class="myButton">12</button>
<button class="myButton">13</button>
<button class="myButton">14</button>
<button class="myButton">15</button>
<button class="myButton">16</button>
<button class="myButton">17</button>
<button class="myButton">18</button>
<button class="myButton">19</button>
<button class="myButton">20</button>
```

There is no need for jquery, and its very fast.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious optimisation is create a function of your click function as the only thing that changes is a single variable.

```
function runActive(x){
   $('body').removeClass('1 2 3 D');
   $('body').addClass(x);
    $('body .buttons div').removeClass('active');   
    $('body .buttons div:nth-child('+x+')').addClass('active');
}

$("body  .buttons div:nth-child(1)").click(function() {runActive('1');}); 
$("body  .buttons div:nth-child(2)").click(function() {runActive('2');}); 
$("body  .buttons div:nth-child(3)").click(function() {runActive('3');}); 
...etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. It will work for any number of buttons. Try it

```
$(".buttons div").click(function() {
  var divClass = $(this).attr('class');
  $('body').removeClass('1 2 3 D');
  $('body').addClass(divClass);
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');  
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a novice answer but will this work?

```
for(i=1; i <= 20; i++) {
    $("body  .buttons div:nth-child(i)").click(function() { 
    for(j=1; j <= 20; i++) $('body').removeClass(String.fromCharCode(63 + n));
    $('body').addClass(i);
    $('body .buttons div').removeClass('active');   
    $('body .buttons div:nth-child(String.fromCharCode(63 + n))').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also optimize the top part of Liam’s answer like bellow:

```
$("body  .buttons div").click(function() {
    // to get the num dynamically. 
    // It depends on your html. For example, you can add an order attribute to each button, order=1, order=2...
    var x = $(this).attr(‘order’);

    runActive(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through these answers and couldn't find the simplest solution i could think of

Simply, when click on any button, get it's class and add it to the body. Add class active to the clicked button and remove class active from others.

Simple and straight forward

See snippet below

```js
var clickMe = $(".buttons div"),
  body = $("body")

clickMe.on("click", function() {
  body.removeClass()
  var butClass = $(this).attr("class")
  body.addClass(butClass)
  $(this).addClass("active")
  $(this).siblings("div").removeClass("active")
})
```

```css
.buttons div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: Red;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.buttons div.active {
  background: green;
}

body.A {
  background: blue;
}

body.B {
  background: yellow;
}

body.C {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="A">1</div>
    <div class="B">2</div>
    <div class="C">3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```